# Redirecting user to a setup script if the web application is not installed

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, redirect, mono, installation

I have a Mono web application with an included setup form. In order to detect if the application is installed or not, I create a marker file _INSTALL_LOCKFILE_ that, if exists, is able to tell that the program is installed (and so Setup will refuse to run *again*).

My question is: how do I redirect the user to the setup script ("~/Setup/Default.aspx") *the first time* he accesses the web application? If user attemts to run the "empty" application he will definitely get unreadable exceptions.

I have thought about using `HttpApplication.BeginRequest` event in Global.asax, or other request-related events, to choose if redirecting or not.

## My doubts are

1. If I say "redirect every request but all that were directed to /Setup/* I will surely be unable to download CSS and images, stored in App_Themes
2. I would not like to enumerate all pages in my web application to write the redirect rules

## So, my question is

How would you redirect the user to a setup script in ASP.NET when you detect that the web application has not been configured yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the life cycle of an application, I think I'd prefer to put such a method in the Application_Start method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    if (!MyLockedFileExists()) {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = “302 Found”;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(“Location”, “http://www.newlocation.com/newwebpage.aspx”);
    }

}
```

<sub>note: `MyLockedFileExists` would be a custom bool method that checks for your lock file</sub>

Comment: Theorically, it's a good idea, but I had problems with that in the past. I was not getting an HttpContext during Application_Start. Also, BeginRequest handles the case in which the user doesn't complete setup and tries to run the web application again...

Comment: did you ensure to add `System.Web` to your includes?